# Does Photoshop have a "randomized stamp" kind of tool yet?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I want to fill up a canvas with individual trees - so I was hoping for a stamp-like tool where I could load up a "sheet" of say, 10 different tree drawings, and then just click around the canvas and the tool would randomly put down one of those 10 trees each time.

Does this kind of thing still not exist in PS? 
So far I've made a group of brushes with a brush for each tree, but picking a new brush each time is still pretty time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such tool in Photoshop unfortunately. I believe Krita has one.

Answer (score 0):

No random stamp tool... but... Photoshop **does** have a **Tree Filter**... designed to create randomized trees.

`Filter > Render > Tree`

[image]

It will generate a tree on a transparent layer. So, you get a great amount of detail without the need to mask anything.

You could create a few trees and then convert them to smart objects. Then duplicate the layers as needed.